# Add Subview at single Index in Custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

is it possible to implement a subview (like an image) at only one row of a UITableViewCell? I'm having an extra class for my Cell. At the moment I call the function with [tblcell addimage]; but it only adds the image at the last cell. Is it possible to add the image at indexPath.row? If yes, how? (I know, that I need to do: [tblcell addimageatIndex:indexPath.row];, that's not the problem, how can I insert the subview at indexPath.row?)

If it helps: I have a nib for the cell.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
[cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
//You will probably need to tweak a bit your UIImageView, so:
myImageView.frame=CGRectMake(value1,value2,value3,value4);//being value* floats
```

Basically you are adding an `UIImageView` into your `cell.contentView`.

Depending on the case, its nice to create a custom UITableViewCell, if you think its simpler than adding UIViews to your normal (`UITableViewCell*`) cell. But in your case, you say:

> at only one row of a UITableViewCell

Only one. So I ask you, is it worth to edit your custom cell just for one? Well, its up to you, but I would probably just add the subView I want into the contentView.